# Is there a way to manipulate only a time value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a very simple calculator that predicts an amount of time based in the speed I will travel and the distance. I have basically a starting hour (e.g. 01:00:00) and I want to add a certain amount of minutes to it and display it back. With some research I managed to get my results using the `Date` object and I parsed the hour string splitting on the `:` character, but the date is completely arbitrary, so I just initialized the `Date` object with day, month and year as a zero value

If the hour extrapolate 24 hours, it doesn't really matter what happens, since is completely unrealistic for my program. Here is the javascript code of what i'm currently using:

```
var speed = document.getElementById("speed").value;
var timeStr = document.getElementById("time").value.split(":");
var prevTime = new Date(0,0,0,timeStr[0],timeStr[1],timeStr[2]);

var newTime = new Date();

newTime.setTime(prevTime.getTime()+ (distance / speed)*60*1000);
```

Is there a more simplistic way to manipulate just a time value?

Comment: If the the actual values are just arbitrary (as in user input) wouldn't it just be numbers and not a point in a calendar?

Comment: It is just numbers, not a point in calendar. I just use dates 0 because I didn't find another way to manipulate hours

Comment: So you need the diff between zero hour and end time?

Comment: `new Date(0,0,0,...timeStr)` can be substituted for `new Date(0,0,0,timeStr[0],timeStr[1],timeStr[2])`

Comment: Thanks for the tip, didn't know that JS had array unpacking like Python, very new to JS